# SQL Server: Partial match of two SQL columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Is there a way i can run a partial match for two SQL columns: I have two SQL columns as given below. Column01 is Integer and Column 02 is string.

```
Column01     Column02
125          Length of room is 125 meter only
```

I am interested to run a partial match and see if the values are Column01 are available in the Column two or not. I have attempted this below coding but it's definitely not working

Where Column02 like '%' + Column01 + '%'

This syntax does runs a partial match but it pulls the results like %Column01% (working as a concatenate function).

Is there a solution to this issue?

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Your expression looks like it does what you intend.  How is it not working?

Comment: This expression is concatenating % sings with the values of Column01, which is not the intention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t TABLE
(
    Column01 VARCHAR(20),
    Column02 VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @t (Column01, Column02)
VALUES ('125', 'Length of room is 125 meter only')

SELECT *
FROM @t
WHERE CHARINDEX(Column01, Column02) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks this is much closer to what i am looking for, Appreciate the Quick help

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is delimiters (so you don't want 125 to match 1250), then you can do something like this:

```
Where ' ' + Column02 + ' ' like '% ' + Column01 + ' %'
```